# Is it possible to install EPD with ia64 system?

Tags: python, enthought

I would like to install EPD_free on a sever. But neither   32-bit version nor 64-bit version of EPD can be installed successfully.

When I run  epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86.sh (32-bit version), I get this:

```
Installing to XXX/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86 ... please wait
epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86.sh: line 313: 31657 Floating point exception$ENPLACE -h >/dev/null
ERROR: failed to run: XXX/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/custom_tools/enplace -h

One reason for this error could be that you are trying to execute a 32-bit
binary on a 64-bit system, which does not have 32-bit shared libraries
installed.
For example, 64-bit Ubuntu 10 or higher, does not contain any 32-bit shared
libraries by default, to install them type: sudo aptitude install ia32-libs
```

XXX stands the directory.

When I run epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64.sh (64-bit version), I get this:

```
Installing to XXX/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64 ... please wait
epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64.sh: line 317: /home/lizz/share/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/custom_tools/enplace: cannot execute binary file
ERROR: failed to run: XXX/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/custom_tools/enplace -h

One reason for this error could be that you are trying to execute a 64-bit
binary on a 32-bit system.
```

The basic imformation of the sever is shown below:

```
$ uname -a
Linux servername 2.6.16.46-0.12-default #1 SMP Thu May 17 14:00:09 UTC 2007 ia64 ia64 ia64 GNU/Linux
```

[here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.epd.user/391) says that *the 64-bit EPD's only support the x86_64 (also known as AMD64) architecture, not IA-64 (Intel Itanium architecture).*

So, anyone can tell how to install EPD with a ia64 system?

Maybe I could install ia32-libs first, then install the 32-bit version? However I have no root pemission. I'll try when waiting for help.

Many thanks.

---

EDIT 2014.4.10

I had posed the wrong question.

The original purpose is to install some scientific python packages  (eg. numpy,scipy,matplotlib) on the server.

The dependency problem is quite painfull, so I thought epd might make it easier. 
However, epd does not support ia64.

Now, it seems [yt](http://yt-project.org/) is a good solution for my question. It contains all the packages which are needed by ipython, numpy, etc.

I'll learn to ask the right question. Thanks for all.

Comment: IA64 is an Itanium system, quite different from an x86-64. Any x86 code you want to execute will require an emulator. My guess is that recompiling it from source is your only option to make it work.

Comment: You can't - you quote an EPD post that say that you can't - why do you think that you can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel Itanium's are not supported by EPD.

There are no plans to have an EPD for IA64 short term. This is mostly due to the level of effort required to maintain the entire set of packages on EPD versus the small group of users that asks for it.